# On grades of torsion modules in noetherian rings

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a (not necessarily commutative) two-sided noetherian ring with minimal injective coresolution $(I_i)$ of the regular module $A$ as a right module.
Say that $A$ has dominant dimension $n$ in case $n$ is the smallest integer such that $I_n$ is not flat (or say that the dominant dimension is infinite in case all $I_i$ are flat).

For a finitely generated module $M$ let $ev_M:M \rightarrow M^{**}$ be the evaluation map, where $M^{*}:=Hom_A(M,A)$ and let $t(M):=ker(ev_M)$ be the torsion module of $M$.

Recall that the grade $gr(M)$ of a module $M$ is defined as $gr(M):= inf \{ i \geq 0 | Ext_A^i(M,A) \neq 0 \}$.

In the article "Homological theory of noetherian rings" Reiten proved in theorem 5.2. that the following are equivalent for a noetherian ring of global dimension 2:

a) $gr(t(M)) \geq 2$ for all finitely generated $M$.

b) $A$ has dominant dimension at least 2.

> Question: Is the following more general statement true?
>
> Let $A$ be a noetherian ring (so we have no restriction on the global dimension now) and $n \geq 2$. Then $A$ has dominant dimension at least $n$ iff $gr(t(M)) \geq n$ for all finitely generated $M$.

One can show that dominant dimension at least $n$ implies $gr(t(M)) \geq n$ for all finitely generated $M$, but I am not sure about the other direction.

Computer experiments suggest that it might be true.